# QSerialPort readyread() SIGNAL

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I have a problem when receiving bytes from RS232 in QByteArray. I connected readyread() signal to call my serialport method and inside it I am reading bytes with readAll() to an QByteArray. Whenever data is available it rewrites QByteArray, but I want to receive it all, and then use data, but now I cannot because it is in parts. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply append to the array. You'll also need some criterion to determine when you've received all the data you wished. This can be, e.g. a given number of bytes:

```
class Communicator {
  int expect;
  QSerialPort port;
  QByteArray reply;
  void processReply() {
    ...
  }
public:
  Communicator() {
    QObject::connect(&port, &QIODevice::readyRead, [this]{
      reply += port.readAll();
      if (expect && reply.size() >= expect) {
        processReply();
        reply.clear();
        expect = 0;
      }
    });
  ...
};
```